# How do I use Doctrine 2.0 ORM models to select database data?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have recently started to learn using of Doctrine 2.0 framework for PHP. Now I have already managed to utilize some Doctrine things (using MySQL), insert some data using defined XML model, but now I have a problem with selecting data. Everywhere, including Doctrine site, I have found that data are being selected by DQL or raw SQL. But in this way, I lose half of advantages that ORM gives. How can I select data using pure ORM, for example like I can do with Hibernate in Java?

Here is some mapping XML example from the Doctrine site I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

      <entity name="Product" table="products">
          <id name="id" type="integer" column="product_id">
              <generator strategy="AUTO" />
          </id>

          <field name="name" column="product_name" type="string" />
      </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [association mappings](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html)?  What exactly do you want to select?

Comment: @Orbling: I haven't started learning association yet, now I am trying to find out just how to retreive data. For example here I would like to get instance of Product class, same as I inserted (using EntityManager::persist()).

Comment: So literally retrieve a single entity by ID? `$product = $entityManager->find('Product', 123);`  It is best to read *all* of the documentation before starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning I missed that one too, but what is important to understand is that DQL doesn't understand concept of tables (read note [DQL is not SQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html#list-of-bugs)) it is purely object-oriented query. That is you query your models, not the database directly.

Manual itself states that DQL "[is very similar to the Hibernate Query Language](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)".

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to read data is to use `EntityManager->find()`, you pass in the class you want to load as the first argument (a string) and the ID of that entity as the second.  I've recently started with Doctrine 2 myself, the best advice I can give you is to read *all* of the docs Orbling linked to above, and to use Annotations instead of XML (at least to start off with).

HTH.

Comment: I will try to use it, thx for advise. I am used to use XML mapping from Java Hibernate, its better habbit for me.

Comment: @James: Like Robin said above and I said in comments, you have to read and digest *all* the docs before starting really.  Otherwise you will end up doing things in an awkward way.